# classification with SVM using vocab build from Bag of Word

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

My intention is to build a classifier that correctly classify the image ROI  with the template that I have manually extracted

**Here is what I have done.** 
My first step is to understand what should be done to achieve the above

I have realized I would need to create the representation vectors(of the template) through research from the net. Hence I have used Bag of words to create the vocabulary

I have used and rewritten the  [Roy's project](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/08/25/a-simple-object-classifier-with-bag-of-words-using-opencv-2-3-w-code/) to opencv 3.1 and also used his [food database](http://www.media.mit.edu/~roys/shared/foodcamimages.zip). On seeing his database, I have realised that some of the image contain multiple class type. I try to clip the image so that **each training image only contains one class of item** but the image are now of different size

I have tried to run this code. The result is very disappointing. It always points to one class.

Question I have?

1. Is my step in processing the training image wrong? I read around and some posts suggest the image size must be constant or at least the aspect ratio. I am confused by this. Is there some tools available for resizing samples?

Comment: It depends on how you extract descriptors. If it's a local descriptor extracted from image it does not matter what is the size of the sample image.

Comment: @AccessDenied So my first step is correct... Wonder why Roy used the whole image(which has several classes of objects)?

Comment: Because image can contain several objects. He is using local descriptors, since he compute them around Points of interest and it does not matter what is the image size.

Comment: @AccessDenied Oh Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. It does not matter what is the size of the sample images, since Roy's algorithm uses local descriptors extracte from nearby points of interest.
2. SVM is linear regression classifier and you need to train different SVM-s for each class. For each class it will say whether it's of that class or the rest. The so called one vs. rest.